# Is there a possibility to use unix domain socket Tor proxy in phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs, tor, unix-socket

I'm using selenium with phantomjs under Ubuntu 16.04. I want to make use of Tor proxy. There is, of course, possibility to set a proxy via host:port pair like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
service_args = [
        '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050',
        '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
```

But I wonder if there is a possibility to make phantomjs use a unix domain socket (configured in Tor, of course) instead of host:port pair.
Setting it simply like `--proxy=/run/tor/tor.socket` does not make the trick - the request to check.torproject.org shows that. Maybe there is some special syntax for that option?

Comment: Does `--proxy=unix:/run/tor/tor.socket` work?

Comment: Nope, it does not.